# mysql join / subquery on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have two tables (slots and items)

```
Table 'slots'

user_id     armor     helmet     weapon                
=======================================            
1           1         5          2
3           NULL      7          2
```

then I have

```
Table 'items'

id     name            type     bonus                
=====================================            
1      Plate Armor     armor    2
2      Katana          weapon   4 
...
```

What I want is to get array like this.

```
$equipment = array(
    'armor' => 'Plate Armor',
    'helmet' => 'Plate Helmet',
    'weapon' => 'Katana'
);
```

How is it possible to achieve this with one query? I'm doing it with one query to get the slots and then loop through them and query for assigned items, but that doesn't seem to be efficient.

Comment: `slots` looks like it's in need of normalisation

Comment: what do you suggest @Strawberry

Comment: Something like `user_id, slot_type, slot_item` but the exact configuration is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `join` for each piece of equipment, and that needs to be a `left join` because your user might not have an equipment on a slot:

```
SELECT  A.name AS armor, H.name AS helmet, W.name AS weapon
FROM    slots AS S
        LEFT JOIN items AS A
            ON A.id = S.armor
        LEFT JOIN items AS H
            ON H.id = S.helmet
        LEFT JOIN items AS W
            ON W.id = S.weapon
WHERE   S.user_id = 1
```

This will return the items for `user_id` 1

Another option is to just do a `LEFT JOIN` to get ALL equipment, one row for each equipment piece:

```
SELECT  user_id, AI.type, I.name
FROM   (SELECT distinct type from items) AS AI
        JOIN slots AS S
            ON 1 = 1
        LEFT JOIN items AS I
            ON  I.id IN (S.armor, S.helmet, S.weapon)
            AND I.type = AI.type
WHERE   S.user_id = 3
```

Comment: Thank you! by the way, is it more efficient than doing one query for slots and then loop through them and query for each slot? What if I have like 10 different slots, is doing 10 joins ok?

Comment: Do you need to pull the information for a single user?

Comment: Yes, I want to load all his equipment.

Comment: @Matumizuro it's vastly more efficient than a loop and vastly less efficient than a properly normalised schema

Comment: See above, another option.

Comment: ok, the 2nd option will bring back all equipment type, and null where there isn't. as for efficiency, it's better than to actually loop through all rows to find the correct one, because you need to loop 10 times, and keep all equipment pieces in memory while trying to find it.

Comment: Yes, this looks cleaner and fetches what I want. Thank you!